# Page navigation in tkinter using functions

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to do navigation in `tkinter` using `functions` as am not abreast with `class programming` but am getting this error `AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute` 'show'. I want to do that so i can have different widgets in all the three frames.

I kindly need your assistance to lift the frame for the next one to appear and also go backwards.

```
import tkinter as tk



def show():
    global show
    gr = tk.Frame(root)
    gr.lift()



def next_page():
    global show
    # move the first page to the end of the list,
    # then show the first page in the list
    page = pages.pop(0)
    pages.append(page)
    pages[0].show()



def prev_page():
    global show
    # move the last page in the list to the front of the list,
    # then show the first page in the list.
    page = pages.pop(-1)
    pages.insert(0, page)
    pages[0].show()





root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("400x400")


Page = tk.Label(root, text="page number")
Page.pack()


buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
container = tk.Frame(root)

buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

next_button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Next", command=next_page) # self.next_page
prev_button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Previous", command=prev_page) # prev_page
prev_button.pack(side="left")
next_button.pack(side="left")



pages = []
for i in range(3):
    page = tk.Label(text="page %d" % i)
    page.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    pages.append(page)
#pages[0].show()


root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

This is my `next_page` function but it doesn't work meanwhile have used `place_forget`

```
def next_page():
    i = var.get()
    if i < 2 :
        pages[i].place_forget()
        var.set(i + 1)
        pages[i+1].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


        if pages[i] == 0:
            pages[i].place_forget()
            tree = ttk.Treeview()
            tree.pack()
        elif pages[i] == 1:
            pages[i].place_forget()
            listbox = tk.Listbox()
            listbox.pack()
        elif pages[i] == 2:
            pages[i].place_forget()
            listbox = tk.Text()
            listbox.pack()
```

Comment: why do you have `global show` in each function?

Comment: Thought that could prevent the error.

Comment: `show` is a `function` and not a `variable`. So it already has a `global` scope

Answer (score 0):

To "hide" label use a `.place_forget()` method , that is associated with the type of a "geometry-manager" your have selected when the widget was created:

```
label.place_forget()
```

If you use `place_forget`, you can later show the widget again calling `place` again.

this is one way :

```
def next_page():
    i = var.get()
    if i < 2 :
        pages[i].place_forget()
        var.set(i + 1)
        pages[i+1].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


def prev_page():
    i = var.get()
    if i > 0:
        pages[i].place_forget()
        var.set(i - 1)
        pages[i-1].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("400x400")

Page = tk.Label(root, text="page number")
Page.pack()


buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
container = tk.Frame(root)

buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

next_button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Next", command=next_page) # self.next_page
prev_button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Previous", command=prev_page) # prev_page
prev_button.pack(side="left")
next_button.pack(side="left")


var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(0)

pages = []
for i in range(3):
    page = tk.Label(text="page %d" % i)
    pages.append(page)
pages[0].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your answer you gave solve it to certain extent i want have widget in all the pages .

Comment: @Bryan Oakley have edit my code with the answer you provided, what the best way i can work around it to achieve it.